# How do I make prepared seitan (gluten) more tender?

Tags: vegan, tenderizing, seitan

The 'chicken' Twinkie-sized logs from Chinese grocer are roughly the texture of firm silicone.

I sliced them thinly and braised for 1 hour. Not noticeably softer.

How do I tenderize them? Would meat tenderizer work? I'm assuming no but I reckon I will get some other good tips!

Answer (score 1):

Some meat tenderizers *will* very likely work since they are proteases, some of which work on plant based proteins too. Try on a small piece and compare.

Frying and simmering will both cook it to an even more firm state (maybe it would eventually cook to mush if you cooked it for days... but one way to MAKE it involves a 3-4 hour simmer :).

I am assuming it is not actually *rubbery* due to being undercooked - in that case your 1 hour braise should have improved it.

Comment: Bromelaine or papain?

Comment: just found: "Gliadin, the other protein, is a densely packed protein with a low surface area to volume ratio (6, 7), making it difficult for enzymes to encounter. In addition, gliadin protein has a large amount of amino acids that are especially difficult to digest. These difficult to digest amino acids are proline and glutamine (8)."